# How to write block matrices on diagonal in nice form?

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Let $Y$ be real $2\times 2$ matrix

\begin{equation*}
Y = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
and $Z$ is block matrix constructed as depicted on the picture bellow[image]

Matrices $Y$ are lying on diagonal of matrix $Z$ and they are overlapping such that gray areas can be writen as $a + d$.

Is there cleaner definition of matrix $Z$ in terms of $Y$ so one has not to write elements of $Z$ elementwise? Can we use Toeplitz matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the matrix is

$$
Z=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&a+d&b\\
&c&a+d&b\\
&&c&a+d&b\\
&&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&&&c&a+d&b\\
&&&&&c&d
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is the Toeplitz matrix $T_n(f)$ generated by $f(\theta)=a+d+ce^{\mathbf{i}\theta}+be^{-\mathbf{i}\theta}$ + the low-rank matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-d\\
\\
\\
\\
&&&&-a
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is a standard scalar-valued tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix plus corner perturbations. No need to do any blocking.

Comment: So it has name "corner perturbations", thank you

Comment: Yes, "corner perturbations" could also indicate a few more elements in the corners that are changed, obvious by context. More general "low-rank perturbation". If you are interested in the eigenvalues or inversion there are closed formulas for many cases; see for example https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/anziam-journal/article/explicit-eigenvalues-and-inverses-of-tridiagonal-toeplitz-matrices-with-four-perturbed-corners/006A7DE595A047355C6C3178AA8E0CBA

Comment: What I really need is determinant of it. But you already helped me a lot

Comment: If you can tell me a,b,c,d then I can tell you if there are closed formulas for the eigenvalues.

Comment: (first of all, you can symmetrize the matrix, which gives a similar matrix, by keeping the same main diagonal and switch the two off diagonals to $\sqrt{b}\sqrt{c}$)

Comment: Ok. $b = c = -\frac{1}{pL}$ and $a = d = pC + \frac{1}{pL}$ where $L,C\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $p$ is complex variable.

Comment: That would be characterized by the $\tau_{\epsilon\epsilon}$-algebra, defined in [1] where $\epsilon=1+p^2LC$ (I would guess you have so-called eigenvalue outliers, since $\epsilon>1$) In some special cases there are formulas for all the eigenvalues in these cases, but I would not count on it (you can post exact numerical examples if interested)  [1] Bozzo and Di Fiori "ON THE USE OF CERTAIN MATRIX ALGEBRAS ASSOCIATED WITH DISCRETE TRIGONOMETRIC TRANSFORMS IN MATRIX DISPLACEMENT DECOMPOSITION"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101686/discussion-between-whoooo-and-jan-filip).